# Unique indices for elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have this list:

```
toFindIn = ['TRANSPARENT ENCAPSULANT EPOXY HARDENER (5225B-KL) 1215807',
            'TRANSPARENT ENCAPSULANT EPOXY RESIN (2282A)',
            'TRANSPARENT ENCAPSULANT EPOXY HARDENER (5225B-KL) 1215807',
            'MELAMINE COMPOUND CT-6005 (FORMALDEHYDE MOLDING COMPOUND, GL AZING POWDER)',
            '(AUTO PARTS FOR CAPTIVE USE) NAMEPLATE COMPASS (PART NO: 533 771200) (QTY: 288 NOS)',
            'TRANSPARENT ENCAPSULANT EPOXY HARDENER (5225B-KL) 1215807']
```

and I would like to print unique index value for each element even though some elements might be repeated. How do I achieve that?

the index list contains:

```
[0, 1, 0, 3, 4, 0]
```

instead I would like it to be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: How do you define _unique index_?

Comment: @mshsayem if you print indices of each element it would print [0, 1, 0, 3, 4, 0]. Instead I would like it as [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: @NeerajLagwankar So, you just want `list(range(len(toFindIn)))`?

Comment: @coldspeed thanks a lot! That helps. Let me see how I can modify it further. Thanks again.

Comment: Or `[i for i, _ in enumerate(toFindIn)]`.

Comment: You may want to store them as a [pandas Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html)

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

```
for index, item in enumerate(toFindIn):
    print(index, ", ", item)
```

Or if you really just want the indexes:

```
for index in range(len(toFindIn)):
    print(index)
```

If what you want is a list of the indexes:

```
indexes = list(range(len(toFindIn)))
print(indexes)
```